# Secure access to Microsoft Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a frontend container, backend container and the azure blob storage. User using the front/backend are authenticated. Thus the backend validates the user credentials and users are allowed to access their media files stored in the azure blob storage.

I would like that users access their media files directly at the azure blob storage in order not to stress the backend to much by using it as a proxy. The media references for each user are stored in the backend.

How would you achieve this by using the azure blob storage and its access control (or is it a misuse of the azure blob storage)?

Comment: what solution did you end up with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement security by generating a **[`SAS token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)** for your blob container/individual blob

With a SAS, you can grant clients access to resources in your storage account, without sharing your account keys